# How do I comment lines in .plist file?

Tags: ios, macos, plist, info.plist

How do I comment out lines in my `.plist` file in my iOS/Mac projects?

I want to comment out the settings that I don't want to expose for this version of the project, but I may want to expose it later.

Answer (score 150, accepted):

Syntax of plist is pretty much like XML, so you can use XML style comments.

```
<!--
<dict>
    <key>Hello</key>
    <string>World</string>
</dict> 
-->
```

Comment: By the way, you can select a portion of plist text and press cmd-/ (like you do for making a single-line comment in regular .m, .h files) and XCode will comment selected block for you automatically.

Comment: Unfortunately cmd-/ no longer works in Xcode Version 11.0 (11A420a)

Answer (score 19):

Xcode seems to believe that the `<comment>` tag corrupts the data. It will also strip out XML-style `<!-- comments -->` when viewing the plist in Xcode. It seems that a string entry, e.g.

```
<key>Comment</key>
<string>My comment</string>
```

is the only way to reliably persist the comments.

Comment: This way of adding a key/string pair still works, xcode9. It conforms to the DTD, http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd

Comment: Mind you, Xcode removes any comments from plist files once they are opened in xcode